# PyQt4 console import error py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get this error from an exe i compiled with py2exe that has PyQt4 in it:
I have no idea how to fix this really, I've tried adding pyqt4 to my exe maker file, but that doesn't help, and I couldn't find it anywhere else here.

```
  File "PyQt4\uic\__init__.pyc", line 236, in loadUi
  File "PyQt4\uic\Loader\loader.pyc", line 71, in loadUi
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 982, in parse
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 803, in createUserInterface
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 781, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 265, in createWidget
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 781, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 265, in createWidget
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 781, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 478, in createLayout
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 781, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 521, in handleItem
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 781, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 256, in createWidget
  File "PyQt4\uic\uiparser.pyc", line 220, in setupObject
  File "PyQt4\uic\objcreator.pyc", line 106, in createQObject
  File "PyQt4\uic\objcreator.pyc", line 131, in findQObjectType
  File "PyQt4\uic\Loader\qobjectcreator.pyc", line 107, in search
  ImportError: No module named console
```

Comment: Can you try with [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/) instead of py2exe with below command.
`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed MyCode.py`

Comment: I'' try, thanks for the reply

Comment: I got this error after compiling

AttributeError: 'Simulation' object has no attribute 'qtgl'
Failed to execute script bluesky